# CFC file reroutes to ColdFusion login window

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When I try to call a .CFC file from a .CFM file, the .CFC file will execute its code, but once its done I'm re-routed to a ColdFusion admin login window. I even went as far as removing all the code from the .cfc file and it still, so essentially it does nothing and it didn't matter, as soon as it finished running the .cfc it went to a ColdFusion login window. I removed the .cfc file and this no longer occurred. What do I have to do to call .CFC files in ColdFusion? Is this a ColdFusion setting?

[image]

Comment: *What do I have to do to call .CFC files in ColdFusion* All depends on what you are trying to do. By default, you cannot access .cfc files directly (for security reasons). However, as mentioned below, you can access `remote` methods via URL. You can also invoke a CFC method via `cfinvoke` or `createObject`. If you need more specific advice, post some code and a brief explanation of the goal.

Comment: It's hard to determine what's up with yer code if you don't show it to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you browse to a CFC, CFCExplorer will run to show you a Javadoc-like generated documentation.  That's why you see that login page.

The code in your CFC got executed is just a side effect of CF instantiating your CFC to inspect its content.

You generally want to do the code execution in a CFM, with CFC used to handle your OO things.

One exception might be `foo.cfc?method=someAjaxMethod&Arg1=bar`, for invoking remote method by ajax.